If $\phi \in L^2(\mathbb T)$ and $\widehat{\phi}(\mathbb Z_{<0}) = \{0\}$, then $\phi \ne 0$ a.e. or $\phi = 0$ a.e. on $\mathbb T$
I would like to show the following result.

Suppose $\phi\in L^2(\mathbb T)$ satisfies $\widehat{\phi}(n) = 0$ for all $n\in \mathbb Z_{<0}$. Then, either $\phi \ne 0$ a.e., or $\phi = 0$ a.e.

The result is quite strong: it says that if $\phi$ vanishes on a set of positive measure (i.e., $\phi \ne 0$ a.e. does not hold,) then $\phi$ vanishes almost everywhere. The hypothesis is
$$\widehat{\phi}(n) = \int_\mathbb{T}\phi(t) \, e^{-2\pi int}\, dt = 0,$$
for all $n\in \mathbb Z_{<0}$. Since
$$\|\phi\|_2^2 = \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z} |\widehat{\phi}(n)|^2,$$
we have $$\|\phi\|_2^2 = \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z_{\ge 0}} |\widehat{\phi}(n)|^2.$$
Suppose $\phi$ vanishes on a set $S\subset\mathbb T$ of positive measure. It will be enough to show that $\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z_{\ge 0}} |\widehat{\phi}(n)|^2 = 0$, for then $\|\phi\|_2^2 = \int_{\mathbb T} |\phi(t)|^2\, dt = 0$ would imply $\phi = 0$ a.e. on $\mathbb T= \mathbb R/\mathbb Z$. We can write
$$\sum_{n\in \mathbb Z_{\ge 0}} |\widehat{\phi}(n)|^2 = |\widehat{\phi}(0)|^2 + \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z_{>0}} \widehat{\phi}(n) \overline{\widehat{\phi}(n)} = |\widehat{\phi}(0)|^2 + \sum_{n\in \mathbb Z_{>0}} \widehat{\phi}(n) \widehat{\overline{\phi}}(-n).$$
I'm not sure where to go from here. Thanks for any help!

Have you tried doing things with the holomorphic function $z\mapsto\sum_{n\geq 0}\widehat\phi(n)z^n$ on the unit disk?

That's a nice idea - what sort of things do you recommend? @P.P.Tuong

assume $\phi$ not identically zero and then wlog we can assume $\widehat{\phi(0)} \ne 0$ as otherwise  we take a factor $e^{ikx}$ that has modulus $1$; then $F(z)=\sum_{n \ge 0}\widehat{\phi}(n)z^n$ is analytic in the unit disc and has radial boundary limit $\phi$ ae while $F(0) \ne 0$; applying Jensen theorem to $F$ we get that $\int_0^{2\pi}\log |F(re^{it}|dt$ increases with $r$ and is at least $2\pi \log |F(0)| >-\infty$ and it converges to $\int_0^{2\pi}\log |\phi(e^{it})|dt$ so $\phi$ cannot be zero on a set of positive measure

without complex function theory, there is a cool proof I learned from a lecture of Helson; one assumes wlog $a_0=\widehat{\phi(0)} \ne 0$ and constructs the closed convex set of functions in $L^2$ given by the closure of the set $\phi(e^{it})(1+c_1e^{it}+...c_ke^{ikt})$ for arbitrary complex coefficients $c_k$ and $k \ge 1$; it has a unique element $g$ of minimum norm by Hilbert space theory and it's easy to see by a simple variational argument ($||g+w e^{ikt}g||^2$ is minimal at zero for all $w$ complex) that $|g|^2$ is constant; so $|g|$ is constant but vanishes (ae) where $\phi$ does.

and crucially, of course, $g$ is not identically zero since its zeroth Fourier coefficient is $a_0 \ne 0$
